# How to open and bind data a angular-ui modal pop up in update mode?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I want to accomplish the following points:
1.  Open a modal popup using angular ui on clicking a button
2.  Bind the data to the controls present in the modal popup

[image]

AngularFormsApp.js:

```
var angularFormsApp = angular.module('angularFormsApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

angularFormsApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/home", {
            templateUrl: "app/Home.html",
            controller: "HomeController"
        })
        .when("/newEmployeeForm", {
            templateUrl: "app/EmployeeForm/efTemplate.html",
            controller: "efController"
        })
        .when("/updateEmployeeForm/:id", {
            templateUrl: "app/EmployeeForm/efTemplateNew.html",
            controller: "efController"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/home"
        });
});

angularFormsApp.controller("HomeController",
    function ($scope, $location, $modal, DataService) {

        $scope.showCreateEmployeeForm = function () {
            //$location.path('/newEmployeeForm');

            $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'app/EmployeeForm/efTemplate.html',
                controller: 'efController'
            });

        };

        $scope.showUpdateEmployeeForm = function (id) {
            $location.path('/updateEmployeeForm/' + id)
            //$modal.open({
            //    templateUrl: 'app/EmployeeForm/efTemplate.html/' + id,
            //    controller: 'efController'
            //})
        };

    });
```

efController.js

```
angularFormsApp.controller('efController',
    function efController($scope, $window, $routeParams, $modalInstance, DataService) {

        if ($routeParams.id)
            $scope.employee = DataService.getEmployee($routeParams.id);
        else
            $scope.employee = { id: 0 };

        $scope.editableEmployee = angular.copy($scope.employee);

        $scope.departments = [
            "Engineering",
            "Marketing",
            "Finance",
            "Administration"
        ];

        $scope.submitForm = function () {

            if ($scope.editableEmployee.id == 0) {
                // insert new employee
                DataService.insertEmployee($scope.editableEmployee);
            }
            else {
                // update the employee
                DataService.updateEmployee($scope.editableEmployee);
            }

            $scope.employee = angular.copy($scope.editableEmployee);
            //$window.history.back();

            $modalInstance.close();
        };

        $scope.cancelForm = function () {
            //$window.history.back();

            $modalInstance.dismiss();
        };

    });
```

DataService.js

```
angularFormsApp.factory('DataService',
    function () {
        var getEmployee = function (id) {
            if (id == 123) {
                return {
                    id: 123,
                    fullName: "Milton Waddams",
                    notes: "The ideal employee.  Just don't touch his red stapler.",
                    department: "Administration",
                    perkCar: true,
                    perkStock: false,
                    perkSixWeeks: true,
                    payrollType: "none"
                };
            }
            return undefined;
        };

        var insertEmployee = function (newEmployee) {
            return true;
        };

        var updateEmployee = function (employee) {
            return true;
        };

        return {
            insertEmployee: insertEmployee,
            updateEmployee: updateEmployee,
            getEmployee: getEmployee
        };
    });
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularFormsApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/AngularFormsApp.js"></script>
    <script src="app/DataService.js"></script>

    <script src="app/EmployeeForm/efController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/EmployeeForm/efDirective.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="container">
    <h1>Start Page</h1>
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Home.html:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add New Employee"
       ng-click="showCreateEmployeeForm()" />
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update Employee Id: 123"
       ng-click="showUpdateEmployeeForm(123)" />
```

I want to set the value of  $routeParams.id but while debugging I saw that this value is not set.
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you look in DataService.js, the insertEmployee() function is just a stub which doesn't do anything.  Normally this would reach out to the database and populate the new Id for the employee.

This is from my Pluralsight course, AngularJS Forms Using Bootstrap and MVC 5.  If you continue watching the course, you'll learn more about this.

As far as setting $routeParams.id goes, you shouldn't be navigating to and from a modal dialog.  If you continue with the course, you'll see how to use a page (ng-view) which can be used for navigation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to populate the dummy data in the modal dialog for update mode. In short I want to display the data for the update mode in the modal dialog. Can you please help me to get the code sample for it.

Answer (score 0):

In **packages.config**,

```
<packages>
  <package id="Angular.UI.Bootstrap" version="0.11.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="angularjs" version="1.2.18" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.9.0" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

**You will need to download these exact package versions, for it to function correctly.**

I used your codes and model form works perfectly. I can send you whole project package if you like to.